# taurus - to assert if redirected url is correct

Tags: taurus

```
scenarios:
   RedirectURL:
   variables:
       baseurl: https://www.example.com
   headers:
       Authorization: example
   retrieve-resources: false
   follow-redirects: true
   requests:
      - url: https://www.example.com
       method: GET
        assert:
          - contains:
          - 301
        subject: http-code
        assume-success: true
```

I see that in Taurus we can check the return codes and also make assertions on the body on the HTML page that will be displayed. Is it possible to capture what URL the page will be redirected to and make an assertion on it? Example: if I expect `https://www.example.com` to be redirected only to `https://www.example.com/test/`, and fail if it redirects to `https://www.example.com/testing/`, how do I achieve it. TIA

Comment: I have the same question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a JSR223 Post-Processor to optionally change the SampleResult to fail

```
scenarios:
  RedirectURL:
     variables:
       baseurl: https://www.example.com
     headers:
       Authorization: example
     retrieve-resources: false
     follow-redirects: true
     requests:
       - url: https://www.example.com
         method: GET
         assert:
         - contains:
           - 200 # Response code of the url after the redirect
           subject: http-code

         jsr223:
           - language: groovy
             execute: after
             script-text: if (prev.getUrlAsString() != 'https://www.example.com/test/') { prev.setSuccessful(false); prev.setResponseMessage('Unexpected URL'); }
```

prev is a https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html